# Why does the Facebook registration page require you to retype the email and NOT the password?

Tags: registration, facebook

Why does Facebook require you to retype your address when you register?

- you already have feedback, so there is no possibility of mistake
- you can just copy-paste the address
- they don’t check it anyway (it is possible to register an account with someone else’s address)

On the other hand, requiring the user to retype the password **would** be useful, since you get no feedback there.

[image: facebook registration page]

Comment: If you get the password wrong you can reset via email. If you get the email wrong - then you're stuck.

Comment: @StewartDean If you get the email wrong, you can register again. The problem is that Facebook does not check the email you entered.

Comment: @kinokijuf Facebook does check the email you entered, by sending an email with a link you must click on. This is the only sane way of ensuring that an email address both exists and is controlled by someone who is complicit in the creation of this Facebook account.

Comment: @PaulGregory you can still register and use the site without activation. After several days, they issue you a “checkpoint” and demand you give them your phone number regardless of whether you have activated, but that’s another issue altogether.

Answer (score 2):

A similar question was [asked on Quora](http://www.quora.com/User-Experience/Why-do-you-need-to-enter-your-email-address-twice-on-most-registration-forms). As **@stewart-dean** stated in an earlier comment, the primary reason seems to be that it helps to verify that a user entered their email address correctly. Passwords can always be reset. Incorrect email addresses cannot.

Comment: -1 for linking to a paywalled site.

Comment: @kinokijuf come on, the informations he is referring to are available even if you're not logged.

Comment: I don't personally think it's worth the -1 - but Quora doesn't let you see the material without logging in.

Comment: @kinokijuf There's a wall, but no pay, and Hynes has summarised the information there. Would you rather Hynes didn't link directly to it, meaning that as well as having to log in you had to find the question?